# how to know precinct of an image prediction?

Tags: python, opencv, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to know the predict precinct of one image

```
classes = model.predict(image)
print(classes)
```

Output:

```
0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
```

I want to show 
[0.95, 0.20 , 0.30 , 0.0 , 0.25 .........]

Comment: Try `predict_proba`

Comment: yes it's what i want thank you